# Niggles of Web App Between IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

This is probably the worst question I have ever posted on Stack Overflow but I am trying to figure out how to fix this page so that it renders the same way in IE7 as it does in IE8.

As far as I can tell there are 3 differences.

The first is that the content becomes centered in IE7.

The second is that the middle section of the video shifts slightly to the right so that it is out of alignment with the top and bottom border images.

The third is that the thumbnail of the active video becomes slightly messed up on the right hand side as if it is too big for its background image.

I could post all the code but I think there's too much for it to be effective on SO.

Here is a link: http://facebook.icrossing.de/tools/youtubetab/esprit/

Perhaps there's someone who has seen this sort of problem before and is able to diagnose a quick and not too painful solution.

Comment: IE9 does not work like IE8 which doesn't work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE6 and none of them work like the other far more modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using the *New* features IE8 has to offer, you should consider using compatibility mode.

[Here is MSDN page on how to define document compatibility.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, I've never actually messed around much with all the different DocTypes. Is there one that you think would solve these issues?

Comment: I would suggest you try `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" >`

Comment: hmm, that's just causing it to render using the IE7 engine or something similar I assume? That's not really what I want to do, I'd rather resolve the issues I am having in IE7 and IE8 Compatibility mode using either css, conditional statements with css or inline css hacks etc.

Comment: @martincarlin87 - Doctypes are required of all new web pages. It's the very first thing to go on a page and is never "messed with". New web pages should always use "strict" and the current one is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Rob I know a little about doctypes but not a lot of the finer details, for 'messed with' read 'experimented' or 'used many of them'. Obviously html is the doctype for HTML 5 but beyond that I couldn't talk at any length about doctypes. Anyway, the question isn't regarding doc types - unless there happens to be a magic one  that will resolve these errors and ergo, my question.

Comment: @martincarlin87 - Without a proper doctype, you are in quirks mode and all hell breaks loose. A doctype is chosen and stuck with throughout. You cannot experiment with them as you go along. The doctype I show is not a HTML5 doctype but a HTML doctype. There is no 5 in it.

Comment: @Rob, yes but I have a doctype and I have stuck with it - it was the answerer who suggested changing doc types! Also, `<!DOCTYPE html>` __is__ the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: @martincarlin87 - No. That is a doctype. While most notable with the introduction of html5 spec, it has nothing to do with html5 itself beyond validation and is used to introduce standards mode in the browser. It works even in browsers that do not support HTML5, such as IE6.

Comment: that may be the case but unfortunately it's not the answer to my question.